# Remove when 2 columns are duplicated, but keep based on value of a third column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking at a way in which to remove all rows which are duplicated on Barcode and Product No., but to keep those duplicated rows when it was their latest Input. Example below:

What I have:

| Input ID | Barcode | Product No. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 225 | 111 |
| 001 | 225 | 111 |
| 001 | 225 | 111 |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 003 | 226 | 222 |
| 003 | 226 | 222 |
| 004 | 226 | 222 |
| 004 | 226 | 222 |
| 005 | 227 | 222 |
| 005 | 227 | 222 |
| 006 | 227 | 222 |
| 006 | 227 | 222 |

Output:

| Input ID | Barcode | Product No. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 002 | 225 | 111 |
| 004 | 226 | 222 |
| 004 | 226 | 222 |
| 006 | 227 | 222 |
| 006 | 227 | 222 |

You can see where the Barcode and Product no. are the same all but the highest Input ID rows have now been removed leaving only duplicates which have the latest input.

Thanks
Oli

Comment: What computer language are we talking about and on what format is the data delivered to the application?

Comment: I'm hopefully looking for a Pandas Syntax to help me out, Imported from a CSV originally

Answer (score 2):

You could run `duplicated` to identify the last duplicate and extend the selection per group using `groupby`+`transform('any')`:

```
df[((~df[['Product No.', 'Barcode']].duplicated(keep='last'))
   .groupby(df['Input ID']).transform('any'))]
```

output:

```
    Input ID  Barcode  Product No.
3          2      225          111
4          2      225          111
5          2      225          111
6          2      225          111
9          4      226          222
10         4      226          222
13         6      227          222
14         6      227          222
```

Comment: My dataset is massive so am just checking to see whether this has worked... but on first looks I think you may have done it! Thank You

Comment: @OliDewes note that you might want to `groupby(['Input ID', 'Barcode'])` in case you have different Barcodes for a given "Input ID" (in this case you need to clarify the expected output).

Comment: Yes so I have looked at the dataset. A Product No may have numerous Barcodes Attributed to it and by the looks of things your initial code has meant there is now only one barcode to each product number (My mistake for not making it clearer). I'm quite new to Python so would I apply the Groupby within the original code or before it? Thank You

Comment: @Oli The code in my answer simply ignores "Barcode", can you please update your question to include an example of IDs with multiple "Barcode" and the output your expect?

Comment: I've just updated. As you can see product number 222 has both barcode 226 and 227 attributed to it. Both barcodes will need to remain in the dataset, but again only the latest input for each one, Hence inputs 004 and 006 remain - Hope this helps

Comment: @Oli check update, you need to add "Barcode" to the duplicate search. Yet, it's still unclear what would happen if the first row had a barcode of 123 for example.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this - within my DataSet it should technically be impossible to have a different barcode but with the same Input ID - as for context adding a new Barcode would count as a New Input. So It should only be the case that a product number can have many barcodes, a barcode can have many Input IDs, but an Input ID can only have one Barcode. I'll let you know if this works!

Comment: @Oli then it should work like you want

Comment: I've just ran it - Number of unique barcodes and Product numbers have remained the same, whilst Input IDs has reduced. Which by my pre-calculations is exactly what should have happened. Thank You!